# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionary0' to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdictionary

I'm incorporating code I got from GitHub and am stuck by an error of 'Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionary0' (0x10bc209c0) to 'NSString'.  The app feature is similar to Tinder's swipe.  The error is coming on the bolded line below:

```
var shot = self.valueArray[i] as! NSDictionary
**let newCard = self.createDraggableViewWithData(at: i, value:(self.shot as NSDictionary? as? String)!)**
```

Here is the createDraggableViewWithData function:

```
    func createDraggableViewWithData(at index: Int , value :String) -> TinderCard {

    let card = TinderCard(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: viewTinderBackGround.frame.size.width - 20 , height: viewTinderBackGround.frame.size.height - 40) ,value : value )
    card.delegate = self
    card.intex = index
    return card
}
```

I think my issue is around delegation but I'm completely lost.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a shoot in the wild, but are you somehow passing a dictionary instead of a string?

Comment: Yes I'm passing a Dictionary. I changed the value parameter to a NSDictionary but that generated an error of 'Cannot convert value of type 'NSDictionary' to expected argument type 'String''

Comment: Well, if you need a `String`, then you need to pass a `String`, not something else. Casting between type doesn't help you much as the underlying data stays the same

Comment: Gotcha. I need a dictionary, I'm not sure why it's giving me the error as I've replaced String

Comment: value:(self.shot as NSDictionary? as? String)! this casting is strange